# Resetting ADC control flags after continuous read (ATMega2560)/Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, cpu-registers, atmega, adc

I am using an ATMega2560 with a resistance touch screen (uses the ADC with `analogRead` commands) – I also use other ADC pins with `analogRead` (NTC temp sensor). This all works fine.

I have recently added a function that requires me to get ADC readings at known intervals and decided that using the automatic sampling was best – I found the code to do this online and it works well for the function it is required for.

My issue is, after I do the continuous sampling, I cannot get the ADC `analogRead` values to return the same as they where before the continuous sample.

I have checked the datasheet and it says the initial value for the  ADCSRA, ADCSRB & ADMUX = 0 – I have tried this and *quite a few* other things with no success.

I have attached some code that does the same as my program – i.e. `analogRead` returns a different value after the continuous sample.

```
byte samplesADC[100];
int samplesADCCount = 0;
bool ADCEnd = false;

void startADCAcquire(){
  int dacChan = 14;
  Serial.println("Start ADC Aquire: ");
  
  cli();//diable interrupts
  
  //set up continuous sampling of analog pin 0
  //clear ADCSRA and ADCSRB registers
  ADCSRA = 0;
  ADCSRB = 0;
  
  ADMUX |= dacChan&0x07;
  if (dacChan >= 8) 
      ADCSRB |= _BV(MUX5);
  else
      ADCSRB &= ~_BV(MUX5);
  ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0); //set reference voltage
  ADMUX |= (1 << ADLAR); //left align the ADC value- so we can read highest 8 bits from ADCH register only

  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS0); //set ADC clock with 32 prescaler- 16mHz/32=500kHz
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADATE); //enabble auto trigger
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIE); //enable interrupts when measurement complete
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN); //enable ADC
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); //start ADC measurements
  sei();//enable interrupts
}

void stopADCAcquire(){
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Stop ADC Acquire");
  cli();//diable interrupts
  
  //set up continuous sampling of analog pin 0
  //clear ADCSRA and ADCSRB registers
  ADCSRA = 0;
 ADCSRB = 0;
  ADMUX = 0;
//  ADCSRB &= ~_BV(MUX5);
//  ADMUX &= ~(1 << ADLAR); 
//   ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADSC);       // disable adc interrupt
  sei();//enable interrupts 
}

void setup(){
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("START");
  Serial.print("Pin A2 (1): ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(A2));
  startADCAcquire();
  int i;
  while(ADCEnd == false){
    i++;
  }
  while ((UCSR0A & _BV (TXC0)) == 0)
    {} 
  Serial.print("Pin A2 (2): ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(A2));
  Serial.println("END");
}

ISR(ADC_vect) {//when new ADC value ready
  samplesADC[samplesADCCount] = ADCH;
  Serial.print(samplesADC[samplesADCCount]);
  Serial.print(", ");
  samplesADCCount++;
  if(samplesADCCount == 100){
   
   stopADCAcquire();
    ADCEnd = true;
  }
}

void loop(){
}
```

Output:

```
START
Pin A2 (1): 0
Start ADC Aquire: 
127, 127, 127...... (x100) 
Stop ADC Acquire
Pin A2 (2): 510
END
```

Comment: Read Nick Gammon on [interrupt](http://gammon.com.au/interrupts).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hcheung...

So I'm not sure if you pointed me to the interrupt page, with reference to the code issues around my interrupt handlers - I think I have sorted these by using volatile variables and removing excess code/print statements from the ISR handler. So thanks for the link - it was a helpful reminder.

However this did nothing to resolve my issue and the output remained the same! On the interrupt page I noticed some code where registers are copied to a buffer and then reassigned later. I decided to try this and copied the ADCSRA, ADCSRB & ADMUX registers on program load and reassigned them after the AD scan.
This also failed - Then as last ditch I copied the registers just before the call to start the AD scan (i.e afer analogRead had been called) and it worked. I am now able to use the analogRead command after my continuous read.

I attach updated code that works - i.e analogRead works after being in continuous mode.

```
volatile byte samplesADC[100];
volatile int samplesADCCount = 0;
volatile bool ADCEnd = false;
uint8_t  ADCSRASave;
uint8_t  ADCSRBSave;
uint8_t  ADMUXSave;


void startADCAcquire(){
  int dacChan = 14;

  ADCSRASave = ADCSRA;
  ADCSRBSave = ADCSRB;
  ADMUXSave = ADMUX;

  cli();//diable interrupts
  
  //set up continuous sampling of analog pin 0
  //clear ADCSRA and ADCSRB registers
  ADCSRA = 0;
  ADCSRB = 0;
  ADMUX |= dacChan&0x07;
  if (dacChan >= 8) 
     ADCSRB |= _BV(MUX5);
  else
    ADCSRB &= ~_BV(MUX5);
  ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0); //set reference voltage
  ADMUX |= (1 << ADLAR); //left align the ADC value- so we can read highest 8 bits from ADCH register only
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS0); //set ADC clock with 32 prescaler- 16mHz/32=500kHz
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADATE); //enabble auto trigger
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIE); //enable interrupts when measurement complete
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN); //enable ADC
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); //start ADC measurements
  sei();//enable interrupts
}

void stopADCAcquire(){
  cli();//diable interrupts
  ADCSRA = ADCSRASave; //0;
  ADCSRB = ADCSRBSave; //0;
  ADMUX = ADMUXSave; //;
  sei();//enable interrupts 
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("START");
  Serial.print("Pin A2 (1): ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(A14));
  Serial.println("Start ADC Aquire: ");
  while ((UCSR0A & _BV (TXC0)) == 0){} 
  startADCAcquire();
   while(ADCEnd == false){  }
  stopADCAcquire();
  for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++){
     Serial.print(samplesADC[x]);
    Serial.print(", ");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Stop ADC Acquire");
  Serial.print("Pin A2 (2): ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(A14));
  Serial.println("END");
}

ISR(ADC_vect) {//when new ADC value ready
  samplesADC[samplesADCCount] = ADCH;
// Serial.print("p");
  samplesADCCount++;
  if(samplesADCCount == 100){
       ADCEnd = true;
  }
}

void loop(){
}
```

Output:

```
START
Pin A2 (1): 511
Start ADC Aquire: 
127, 127, 127, 127 <<< x 100
Stop ADC Acquire
Pin A2 (2): 511    <<< value now same as first
END
```